# Excel calculate smallest of X columns within Y columns, ignoring zeros

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, min

I'm trying to calculate the sum of best segments in a run. For example, each Km gives a list as such:
5:40 6:00 5:45 5:55 6:21 6 :30

I'm trying to gather the best segments of 2km/3km/4km etc and would like a simple code to do it. At the moment, I'm using the formula

```
=Min(If(B1=0,9:9:9,sum(A1:B1),If(C1=0,9:9:9,sum(B1:C1))
```

but this goes all the way to 50km, meaning a very long formulae that I then have to repeat slightly differently at 3km, then 4km, then 5km etc. Surely there must me a way of
generating an array of summed columns of every n column, then iterating over that to find the min while ignoring values of 0?
I can do it manually for now, but what if I want to go over 50km? I might want to incorporate bike rides/car drives in the future just for some data analysis so I figured it best finding an ideal formulae now.

It's frustrating as I could code it and I want to avoid VBA ideally and stick to formulae in Excel.

Comment: It's an interesting question! Could really do with some more sample data (including zeroes) and expected results, also if you testing the first of each pair should the formula be =Min(If(B1=0,9:9:9,sum(A1:B1),If(B1=0,9:9:9,sum(B1:C1)) ? What if the second one of the pair is zero but not the first one?

Comment: Happy to give it! Basically from strava you can get the amount of time it took to get to each km, split by 1km each time. So 0-1,1-2,2-3 etc so there will not be a scenario where there will be a 0 followed by a number. Having said that, the present formula already negates the issue as it always checks the last entry of the summed columns for a value (B1 in the first instance, then C1 then D1). I'll drop a chonk of the formula here for you to see

Comment: =IF(Y3=0,"",MIN(IF(Y3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(X3:Y3)),IF(Z3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(Y3:Z3)),IF(AA3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(Z3:AA3)),IF(AB3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AA3:AB3)),IF(AC3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AB3:AC3)),IF(AD3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AC3:AD3)),IF(AE3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AD3:AE3)),IF(AF3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AE3:AF3)),IF(AG3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AF3:AG3)),IF(AH3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AG3:AH3)),IF(AI3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AH3:AI3)),IF(AJ3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AI3:AJ3)),IF(AK3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AJ3:AK3)),IF(AL3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AK3:AL3)),IF(AM3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AL3:AM3)),IF(AN3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AM3:AN3)),IF(AO3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AN3:AO3)),IF(AP3=0,MAXTIME,SUM(AO3:AP3)))

Comment: OK, thanks for clarification. I was about to post a partial solution for the case where there aren't any zeroes, then it's possible to build on that.

Comment: I might not get to this this morning, but if you do have zeroes in a pair (or group of 3 etc) do you want to (a) ignore the pair entirely as in your formula or (b) try and work out a weighted sum based on the non-zero value? I don't think (b) would be much more difficult than (a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a draft of the case where there aren't any zeroes just for groups of 2Km. I decided the simplest approach initially was to add a couple of helper rows containing the running total of times (and for later use counts) and use a formula like this to subtract them in pairs:

```
=MIN(INDEX(A2:J2,SEQUENCE(1,9,2))-IF(SEQUENCE(1,9,0)=0,0,INDEX(A2:J2,SEQUENCE(1,9,0))))
```

but if you have access to recent additions to Excel 365 like Scan you can do it without helper rows.

[image]

Here is a more realistic scenario with a couple of zeroes thrown in

```
=LET(runningSum,Y$4:AP$4,runningCount,Y$5:AP$5,cols,COLUMNS(runningSum),leg,X7,
seqEnd,SEQUENCE(1,cols-leg+1,leg),seqStart,SEQUENCE(1,cols-leg+1,0),
times,INDEX(runningSum,seqEnd)-IF(seqStart=0,0,INDEX(runningSum,seqStart)),
counts,INDEX(runningCount,seqEnd)-IF(seqStart=0,0,INDEX(runningCount,seqStart)),
MIN(IF(counts=leg,times)))
```

[image]

Note that there are no runs of more than seven consecutive legs that don't contain a zero so 8, 9, 10 etc. just work out to 0.

As mentioned you could dispense with the helper rows by using Scan, but not everyone has access to this so I will add it separately:

```
=LET(data,Y$3:AP$3,runningSum,SCAN(0,data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
runningCount,SCAN(0,data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+(b>0))),leg,X7,cols,COLUMNS(data),
seqEnd,SEQUENCE(1,cols-leg+1,leg),seqStart,SEQUENCE(1,cols-leg+1,0),
times,INDEX(runningSum,seqEnd)-IF(seqStart=0,0,INDEX(runningSum,seqStart)),
counts,INDEX(runningCount,seqEnd)-IF(seqStart=0,0,INDEX(runningCount,seqStart)),
MIN(IF(counts=leg,times)))
```

Comment: Can't wait to see the scan version, I do have office 365 too. Thank you for your efforts so far, I can't wait to try them out

Answer (score 0):

Tom that worked! I learnt a few things on the way too and using the indexing method alongside sequence and columns is something I had not thought of. I'd never heard of the LET command before and I can already see that this is going to really help with some of the bigger calculations in the future.

Thank you so much, I'd like to show you how it now looks. Row 3087 is my old formula, row 3088 is a copy of the same data using the new formula, as you can see I've gotten exactly the same results so it's clear that it works perfectly and it is can be easily duplicated.
[image: Fitness Book.xlsx]